# How to create a tensor of given shape and interval?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am going through Pytorch and want to create a random tensor of shape 5X3 in the interval [3,7)

torch.rand(5,3) will return a random tensor of shape 5 X 3, however, I could not figure to set the given interval.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `U ~ [0, 1]` to `U ~ [a, b]` with `u -> (a - b)*u + b`:

```
(a - b)*torch.rand(5, 3) + b
```

Comment: Can you please also explain this expression [3, 7) , what does it actually signify?

Comment: Sorry, which expression?

Comment: i mean interval.. [3, 7)

Comment: `torch.rand` samples from the uniform distribution on the interval `[0, 1)`. Therefore, the linear transformation above will sample uniformly on  `[3, 7)`. It means "between 3 and 7, including 3, excluding 7" if that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

Define the minimum and maximum value and use the code below:

```
import torch
max = 7
min = 3
rand_tensor = (max-min)*torch.rand((5, 3)) + min
```

Comment: should max be 8 or 7?

Comment: 8. The values range will be from 3 to less than 8

Comment: please refer to ivan comment

Comment: The code you've provided samples from `U ~ [3,8)`, not `U ~ [3,7)`...

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought maximum range was 8. Editted.